# $\text{GL}(V)$ is open in $\text{L}(V,V)$ where V is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have to show that $\text{GL}(V)$, the subset of $\text{L}(V,V)$ of all invertible lineair mappings, is an open set in $\text{L}(V,V)$ where $V$ is a Banach space. When $V$ is finite-dimensional, we can use the continuity of the determinant mapping. So that case is not that hard. The case that $V$ is infinite-dimensional: I thought I have to prove to prove the elementary way. So show that for all $A$ in $\text{GL}(V)$ there is $r>0$ such that $\text{B}(A,r)$ is a subset of $\text{GL}(V)$. So I have to show that elements in the set $\{B\in \text{L}(V,V)\colon ||B-A||<r \}$ are all invertible. I don't know how to show that. Is this is a good way to go? I need hints. Thanks.

Comment: A standard technique is to show that it contains a neighborhood of $\mathrm{id}$ using powerseries expansion of $(\mathrm{id}+x)^{-1}$, and deducing the result from there.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat it is given that the sphere about Id with radius 1 is a subset of GL(V), but I don't know how to use this fact. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: If $A\in GL(V)$, then $B\in GL(V) \iff AB \in GL(V)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer could you explain why this is useful? I don't see it.

Comment: Do you see why for $A\in GL(V)$ the map $T\mapsto A\circ T$ is a homeomorphism of $L(V,V)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, because its continuous and its bijective (both can be easily shown). The inverse is then $T\rightarrow A^{-1}T$ is also continuous. Of course $A$ need to be invertible.

Comment: Right. Hence if $U$ is open, so is $A\cdot U = \{ A\circ T : T\in U\}$. Now you know $B(I,1) \subset GL(V)$. What is $$\bigcup_{A\in GL(V)} A\cdot B(I,1)\;?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I think its GL(V). Both inclusions can be shown by element-chasing. So the conclusion, I suppose, is that the union of open sets is open again, so GL(V) is open.

Comment: Indeed. You can of course also show it's open by writing down the Neumann series for $(B-A)^{-1}$ where $B\in GL(V)$ and $\lVert A\rVert < \lVert B^{-1}\rVert^{-1}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for helping!

Comment: The proof can be found in the book "Analysis tools with applications, Bruce K. Driver" Corollary 4.21.